# how to detect grid view empty cell

Tags: asp.net

**how to detect grid view empty cell ?**  I need it for highlighting. So I made a css

```
.RedColored 
{
    background: FF0000;
}
```

and trying to appear it to empty GV cells this way :

```
protected virtual GridView1_RowDataBound (_sender : object,  e : System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) : void
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "wide";
            foreach(i : int in [0..e.Row.Cells.Count-1])
            {
                when(e.Row.Cells[i].Text==null)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].CssClass="RedColored";
                }
            }
        }
```

but my it doesn't appears to empty cells , even I've tried 
Text=="" , Cell[i]==null, Cell[i].ToString()=="" and nothing helped.

```
recoded to :            

def IsCellNull(cell : TableCell) : bool
            {
                | null => true
                | c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.ToString()) || c.GetType().Name == "DBNull"
        }

            foreach(i : int in [0..e.Row.Cells.Count-1])
            {
                when(IsCellNull(e.Row.Cells[i]))
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Text="BLABLA";
                    e.Row.Cells[i].CssClass="RedColored";
                }
            }
```

> **But !!! It even doesn't helped , it works without WHEN, but when (if) can not find empty cells :P**
>   Finally : solved with this code :`            e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "wide";

```
        def IsCellNull(cell : TableCell) : bool
        {
            | null => true
            | c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.ToString()) 
            || c.GetType().Name == "DBNull" 
            || c.Text=="&nbsp;"
        }

        foreach(i : int in [0..e.Row.Cells.Count-1])
        {
            when(IsCellNull(e.Row.Cells[i]))
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some browsers, the cell will not display a color if it is empty. Adding a space in it solves this issue, but then it will no longer be empty...

To test a cell, you should use string.IsNullOrEmpty():

```
when(string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[i].Text))
{
  e.Row.Cells[i].Text=" "; // Or sometimes a no break space - &nbsp; will work better
  e.Row.Cells[i].CssClass="RedColored";
}
```

Comment: when(e.Row.Cells[i].Text==null)
             {
                 e.Row.Cells[i].Text="BLABLA"; it doesn't works for my empty cells.

Comment: @nCdy - use IsNullOrEmpty to check strings.

Answer (score 3):

`"When a bound GridView cell contains no data, ASP.NET fills it with &nbsp; Hence the length of 6"`

http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/768857-how-check-if-cell-gridview-empty

Comment: it fills the cell with the html entity &nbsp;  (non-breaking space), it looks like a blank space but it is actually 6 characters long in the source

Comment: Got it, thanks!  I wasn't sure if that was part of your answer or formatting.

Comment: in this case when(e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Equals("&nbsp;")) should find the "empty" cell

Answer (score 1):

I have wrote a utility function for this in the past, it is in VB.NET but should be pretty straighforward to convert to C#

> Public Shared Function
>   IsCellBlank(ByVal cell As
>   DataGridViewCell) As Boolean
>
> ```
>     If (cell.Value Is Nothing) Then
>         Return True
>     End If
>
>
>
>     If (cell.Value.ToString().Length = 0)
> ```
>
> Then
>
> ```
>         Return True
>     End If
>
>     If (cell.Value.GetType().Name = "DBNull") Then
>         Return True
>     End If
>
>
>     Return False
> End Function
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected void grdList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {                
      if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text.Equals("&nbsp;"))
      {
          e.Row.Cells[3].BackColor = Color.Red;
      }
   }
}
```