# how to get TableCell value or detect if cell is empty in asp.net app

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, .net-4.5

e.g. in method

```
protected void GridView2_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    foreach (TableCell ecell in e.Row.Cells) {
    }
}
```

I don't know how can I check cell value or if cell is empty?

p.s.: solution from this ( [how to detect grid view empty cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598243/how-to-detect-grid-view-empty-cell) ) question deosn't work anymore because `cell.ToString()` returns .net class name now.

Comment: Try use `cell.Text` property

Comment: @progpow it's same for all data fields ( null or empty )

Comment: Can you add code where you fill table(adding row)?

Comment: @progpow I just set GridView DataSource in designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get data at RowCreated event. It's call before the GridView control can be rendered.This enables you to provide an event-handling method that performs a custom routine, such as adding custom content to a row, whenever this event occurs. Summing, ***You can customisizing View on this step.*** For access to data at adding row you must handler *`RowDataBound`* event

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
       {
          string cellVal = cell.Text;
       }
    }
 }
```